# Best Plane Crash scene in terms of Sound Design?

Tags: plane, crash, soundscapes, fps

I'm trying to create a first person soundscape and one part is a plane crashing in the water whilst on board.

I'd like to get your opinions on which plane crash scenes in TV, Film or Games are the best so I can study them to create my own ideas?

I personally like the various LOST plane crash scenes and the cutscene in Modern Warfare 3, but which are yours?

Answer (score 3):

fight club's mid air collision is one of the best.

[youtube]UAj8_G9tF0k[/youtube]

castaway - also epic

[youtube]IyOu9xCNMK0[/youtube]

dark nights Bane plane heist scene was the best scene of the whole film. (no youtube there, sorry)

Comment: cant go wrong with Ren Klyce, Randy Thom and Richard King!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this film but after watching a short screening of this scene at film school, I kind of want to. I like this scene because watching and listening to it made me feel really uncomfortable, it's just the way I imagine when I'm on a plane, I feel very paranoid thanks to doco's like Aircrash Investigation haha. The one in Cast Away is quite cool as well.

[youtube]iLLcH0x1kwg[/youtube]

Comment: Yeah i was going to say this too. Good tension and release. It's like the biggest drop.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for castaway.
Love how the tension builds up the moments before things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The one in The Grey was pretty impressive

http://youtu.be/iLLcH0x1kwg

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXwB7_dOtA4

This scene from The Knowing. I saw it in the cinema and it was huge! Really convincing as well. Unfortunately the youtube clip doesn't do it justice.

Edit: Sorry I didn't see that you said 'inside' the plane.

Answer (score 0):

[youtube]BVCfo6CLkb0[/youtube]

Teaser from Prey 2

Answer (score 0):

The one in English Patient.